# Underscore js vs Loadash Js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Does ES6 mean the end Of Underscore / Lodash?
Every now and then I see enough need to install one of them. But, more often than not I turn to the ES5 and ES6 counterparts for the methods that I use frequently.

For example, some underscore -> es5/es6 array methods:

```
each -> forEach
map -> map
reduce -> reduce
find -> find
filter -> filter
contains -> includes
```

Which one would you prefer and why?

Comment: Also excellent pointers on native vs. lodash: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Know-Lodash-Underscore#_each

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to use `_.each` or `_.find` from `lodash`, but you still could continue using utils functions from `lodash`, like `_.throttle` or `_.isPlainObject` as `Lodash` supports now module approach.
Check out comment of Dan Abramov creator of `redux` library which is written on top of `es6`, about this:

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/605691126549508096?lang=en